# Declaring javascript object in a js file.

Tags: javascript, html

I want to declare a object in a js file like: 
      var o = {p:1};

and then create a watch for it in my html file.

```
  <script>

  var o = {p:1}; 

  o.watch("p",function (id, oldval, newval)
  { 


  alert(newval);
  return newval; 
  }); 

  o.p=count;
  </script>
```

this code works in my html but if I declare "var o' in my js file it does not work. The reason I want to do that is because a I want to modify the value of my object in my js file and detect it in the html.

Comment: You had better post your whole html code too

Comment: write under `<script`> tag or in `.js` file is similar.  are you adding `<script>` in `.js` file

Comment: ...and while you're at it, you might as well include your whole CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I can think of to track changes to object vars is to use a setter func instead of updating the value directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var o = { 
    p:1,
    q:0,
    watches: [],
    setProp: function(prop, newVal) {
      var oldVal = this[prop];
      this[prop] = newVal;
      if(typeof(this.watches[prop]) == 'function')
      {
         this.watches[prop](prop, oldVal, this['prop']);
      }
    }
  }; 

  o.watches["p"] = function (id, oldval, newval) {
    alert(newval);
    return newval; 
  }; 

  o.setProp('p', count);
  o.setProp('q', 0 - count);
</script>
```

This is about the simplest thing I can come up with, though you'd probably want to add some better error-checking or maybe an addWatch(prop, func) method to o.

Comment: nb: this isn't very secure or reliable code. I wouldn't use it in production as-is but gives you an idea :)